# Get method ( Odata) - check if works correctly - C#

Tags: c#, odata

I am new to c# testing and wondering if this test is working properly based on my test file. If any adjustments needs to be made, feel free to adjust my test file to answer. Thanks

Here is the test file

```
 [TestMethod()]
  public void GetAPI_FIRM_LINKTest1()
    {
      //Arrange
      API_FIRM_LINKController controller = new API_FIRM_LINKController();
      //ACT
      controller.GetAPI_FIRM_LINK();
      var result = controller.GetAPI_FIRM_LINK();
      //Assert
      Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Console.Write(result);
```

Here is part of the file that I am trying to test it

```
   // GET: odata

 [EnableQuery]
 public SingleResult<API_FIRM_LINK> GetAPI_FIRM_LINK([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
 return SingleResult.Create(db.API_FIRM_LINK.Where(aPI_FIRM_LINK => aPI_FIRM_LINK.ApiFirmLinkId == key));
    }
```

Comment: Does the test pass?

Comment: It is passing at the moment

Comment: @devNull not calling ODATA I think